# Since fat is turned into water and CO2, would a person with more fat deposits survive longer without drinking?

Tags: body-fat, metabolism

Based on https://www.bmj.com/content/349/bmj.g7257, far in our bodies is turned into water and CO2. Would this mean that a person with more adipose tissue can survive longer without water?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_water doesn't completely answer my question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_water gives some clues but doesn't answer the question